# How to lazy load a js file in React (for a multilingual app)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, lazy-loading, multilingual

I would like to create a multilingual app with React.

The way I see it would be to have a js file for each language, for example :

**en.js:**

```
module.exports = {
    langEnglish: 'English',
    langFrench: 'French',

    navHome: 'Home',
    navUsers: 'Users',
    ...
};
```

**fr.js:**

```
module.exports = {
    langEnglish: 'Anglais',
    langFrench: 'Français',

    navHome: 'Accueil',
    navUsers: 'Utilisateurs',
    ...
};
```

As each language file will be quite big and there could be dozens of different languages supported, I would prefer to download only the correct file to use depending on the language chosen in order to minimize loading time (and bandwidth usage).

For example I could have a variable in the app state

```
var App = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function () {
        return {
            lang: 'en'
        };
    },

    ...
```

and some user control to switch this variable between `fr` and `en`.

Is it possible to load only the `en.js` file on the initial load, and if the user switches the language to French then load and use the `fr.js` file instead and so on for each language?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make use of some advanced [**webpack**](https://webpack.github.io/) features, such as code splitting. You can use webpacks [`require.ensure`](https://webpack.github.io/docs/code-splitting.html#commonjs-require-ensure) for async loading your files.

Create a file:

#### i18n.js

```
var currentTranslation = {};

module.exports = {
    getTranslation: function() {
        return currentTranslation;
    },

    loadI18n: function(region, cb) {
        switch (region) {
            case 'en':
                require.ensure([], function(require) {
                    cb(currentTranslation = require('./en'));
                }, 'i18n-en'); // will create a chunk named 'i18n-en'
                break;
            case 'fr':
                require.ensure([], function(require) {
                    cb(currentTranslation = require('./fr'));
                }, 'i18n-fr'); // will create a chunk named 'i18n-fr'
                break;
            default:
                require.ensure([], function(require) {
                    cb(currentTranslation = require('./en'));
                }, 'i18n-en');
        }
    }
}
```

#### App.js

```
var i18n = require('./i18n');
```

and when you need the translation strings to be loaded async

you can call:

```
i18n.loadI18n('en', function(texts) {
    console.log(texts);
});
```

once webpack loads that chunk, you will be able to get the translation texts using the function

```
var texts = i18n.getTranslation(); // call this from anywhere and it will return english texts
```

if you want to switch language, just call

```
i18n.loadI18n('fr', function(texts) {
    console.log(texts);
});

var texts = i18n.getTranslation(); // will return french texts
```