# React check if css has loaded with Webpack and React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm developing a project in React with Webpack in ES2015.

I am importing the styles as

`import '../assets/main.scss'`

it works fine, but seems to take longer than the rest of the page, so for a second, everything looks very ugly.

is there a way I can check if the style has been loaded before start rendering the page?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> *"for a second, everything looks very ugly."*

This phenomenon is called [**FOUC**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_of_unstyled_content) (Flash of unstyled content).

#### Solutions:

Since you are using webpack, you'd be using webpack loaders too. So the first level of optimization can be done in your `webpack.config.js`.

**Use webpack's [ExtractTextWebpackPlugin](https://github.com/webpack/extract-text-webpack-plugin).**

> It moves every `require("style.css")` in entry chunks into a separate
>   css output file. So your styles are no longer inlined into the
>   javascript, but separate in a css bundle file (`styles.css`). If your
>   total stylesheet volume is big, it will be faster because the
>   **stylesheet bundle is loaded in parallel to the javascript bundle**.

The text in bold is our first key to kill FOUC.

example:

```
var ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
    module: {
        loaders: [
            // Extract CSS during build
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style', 'css')
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        // Output extracted CSS to a file
        new ExtractTextPlugin('[name].[chunkhash].css')
    ]
}
```

You can tweak this further to use different loaders for `.scss` or `.less`.

> The `ExtractTextPlugin` generates an output file per entry, so you
>   must use `[name]`, `[id]` or `[contenthash]` when using multiple
>   entries.

Create multiple instances of `ExtractTextWebpackPlugin` if your want different bundles for your different loader patterns (as described in the last section of the [API doc](https://github.com/webpack/extract-text-webpack-plugin/blob/webpack-1/README.md#api)).

**So what we achieve ?**

- Separates styling from JavaScript neatly
- Fewer style tags (older IE has a limit)
- CSS SourceMap (with `devtool: "source-map"` and `css-loader?sourceMap`)
- Load CSS in parallel to JS (doesn't have to wait for JavaScript to load to get styling information)
- Separate caching of our CSS files and smaller JS files.
- Faster runtime (less code and DOM operations)

*Nota Bene:* There are some caveats for using `ExtractTextWebpackPlugin` which are also described in the original [documentation page](https://github.com/webpack/extract-text-webpack-plugin/blob/webpack-1/README.md#api).

**Separate CSS bundle and Webpack's Code Splitting** [[*official doc*]](https://webpack.github.io/docs/stylesheets.html#separate-css-bundle)

> With Code Splitting we can use two different modes:
>
> - Create one css file per initial chunk (see [Code Splitting](https://webpack.github.io/docs/code-splitting.html)) and
>     embed stylesheets into additional chunks. (recommended)
> - Create one css file per initial chunk which also contains styles from additional chunks.

For big web apps it’s not efficient to put all code into a single file, especially if some blocks of code are only required under some circumstances. Webpack has a feature to split your codebase into “chunks” which are loaded on demand.

Code splitting can be done Using webpack's [`require.ensure`](https://webpack.github.io/docs/code-splitting.html#commonjs-require-ensure) by defining multiple split. This is pretty easy to configure see [official doc](https://webpack.github.io/docs/code-splitting.html#commonjs-require-ensure), or my own [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40756177/how-to-lazy-load-a-js-file-in-react-for-a-multilingual-app/40756726#40756726) for a [React.js](https://facebook.github.io/react/)-[React-Router](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router)-[Webpack](https://webpack.github.io/) application ;)

There was an an [issue](https://github.com/webpack/extract-text-webpack-plugin/issues/120) reported when async-injection of css splits `ExtractTextWebpackPlugin` and `require.ensure` are used together, and here is the unofficial solution for that (use file-loader and extract-loader combined):

```
{
     test: /\.css$/,
     loaders: ["style-loader/url","file?name=app/[name].[hash].css!extract","css-loader","postcss-loader"]
}
```

**Needs more improvement?**

Once we have configured `ExtractTextWebpackPlugin`, further optimization of CSS can be done using [PurifyCSS WebPack Plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/purifycss-webpack-plugin).

> This is a plugin for WebPack that utilizes [PurifyCSS](https://github.com/purifycss/purifycss) to clean your CSS and removes unused code.

---

> *"Is there a way I can check if the style has been loaded before start rendering the page?"*

Here is a list of reference links explaining some general techniques to minimize FOUC:

- http://johnpolacek.com/2012/10/03/help-prevent-fouc/
- http://www.learningjquery.com/2008/10/1-way-to-avoid-the-flash-of-unstyled-content
- http://www.paulirish.com/2009/avoiding-the-fouc-v3/
- [Authoring Critical Above-the-Fold CSS](https://css-tricks.com/authoring-critical-fold-css/)